str.replace() no selecciona la parte que deberia en la columna de mi dataframe
Se que hay otras formas de hacerlo, pero no entiendo porque esto no funciona. Quiero limpiar la columna position.
Este es el dataframe:
nba = pd.read_csv('https://storage.googleapis.com/humai-datasets/aws_s3/machine_learning/3_Regularizacion_y_feature_engineering/nba_salarios_2021.csv')

al ver nba['position'].value_counts() me da como resultado:
position
SG       92
C        83
PF       78
SF       73
PG       65
PF-C      3
SF-PF     3
SF-SG     2
SF-C      1
PF-SF     1
SG-PG     1
PG-SG     1

Quiero quedarme solo con la primera posicion de los jugadores que se repite, intenté:
nba['position'] = nba['position'].str.replace('-.+', '')
nba['position'] = nba['position'].str.replace('/-.+/g', '')

pero no funciona.

De la documentación de pandas.Series.str.replace traducido libremente:

Series.str.replace(pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0, regex=False)
Parámetros:

...

regex: bool,  por defecto False
Determina si el patrón pasado es una expresión regular:

Si es True, asume que el patrón es una expresión regular.

Si es False, trata al patrón como una cadena literal.


No se puede establecer en False si pat es una expresión regular compilada o repl es un callable.



Le estás pasando una cadena y como regex es False por defecto se interpreta como tal, es decir busca y reemplaza la cadena literal, en vez de tratarla como una expresión regular.
Tanto si le pasas una expresión regular compilada (re.compile()) o una cadena,  debes llamarla con regex=True:
import re
patt = re.compile(r"\-.+$")
nba['position'] = nba['position'].str.replace(patt, '', regex=True)


nba['position'] = nba['position'].str.replace(r"\-.+$", '', regex=True)


Excelente! Gracias!
